# I can't quite get the results to be fully unique - Linux pipelining

Tags: linux, controller, pipeline

I'm almost there... I'm supposed to end up with is 340 unique services.  So far, I can only get it down to 341.

These are my tasks:

1. Extract all the service names from the file.
2. Sort the names alphabetically removing any duplicates.
3. Remove any blank lines or lines that do not contain letters of the
   alphabet.
4. Capture the final output to a file named 'uniqueservices.txt'.
5. Count the lines in the file using a conditional command that is only
   executed if the previous combined commands are successful.

This is the command I used:

`cat /etc/services | grep -Ev '^#|^$' | cut -f1 | sort -u > uniqueservices.txt && wc -l uniqueservices.txt`

Here's what I should get:

[This is what I should get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eztT4.png)

This is what I actually get:

[What I actually get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Br1Z2.png)

I'm guessing there are (as always) better ways of doing this but... hey, I'm new to this.  So close though!

Thanks in advance.

S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `cut -f1` part of your command determines what "column 1" means by scanning the lines for TAB separators. The unmatched line you're seeing likely just uses a space character instead.
I suppose the easiest thing to do would be to just run `cut` again but looking for spaces instead of TABs.

`cat /etc/services | grep -Ev '^#|^$' | cut -f1 | cut -d' ' -f1 | sort -u > uniqueservices.txt && wc -l uniqueservices.txt`

Comment: Ahhhhh, nice one @Raxi that's perfect.  I just assumed I couldn't pipe to the same  command as previous.  Thank you.  I don't have enough rep to upvote you... but it's there in kind. :)

Comment: No worries. And yes, the pipes are handled by the shell really, not the application itself. When you run a single program such as `nano /etc/services`, a `nano` process is created for which stdin is connected to your terminal (so you can type stuff) and stdout is likewise connected to your terminal so stuff is printed to your screen. when you run `cat /etc/services | sort | head -5` then along the way 3 processes are created, where stdout of `cat` is simply hooked up to stdin for `sort` and `sort`s stdout->`head`s stdin, and `head`'s stdout is your terminal again.